# Why isn't there an undo for recent activity by users who get put on timeout?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, account-suspension

As background information, earlier today I noticed some kind of suspicious behaviour on a question (that I think has been deleted) involving [a user who has since been suspended](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191018/hamid-reza-mansouri).

I made a comment about how the answer was suspicious, and I flagged the answer. I think someone else may have flagged it as well, because someone did upvote my comments on the suspicion.

This happened about 7 hours ago. The account was suspended some point after that, but I notice now that about 6 hours ago, I received a whole bunch of downvotes on my responses to older questions.

It seems pretty obvious to me what happened there, so my question/suggestion is how come when the user's account was suspended and the rep locked at 1 wasn't some sort of system in place to undo the last day's worth (or whatever) of voting behaviour?

I guess reputation is of different value to different people, and I know we can't stop all gaming of the system but I'm not sure that we should allow uses who get caught gaming the system to have their "revenge". But maybe it's not worth whatever work to implement some sort of fix? I dunno.

Comment: One reason not to comment a downvote or flag ^^^

Comment: Check again tomorrow - hopefully the fraud filter will have reverted everything.  An auto-undo sounds cool, but I suspect it would be tricky to implement, even for someone as sharp as Nick Craver

Comment: Ah. I didn't know about the fraud filter (or didn't understand it would do this). Thanks.

Comment: The downvotes might be completely unrelated; the downvotes might be done by a different user account. Hopefully the fraud-detection tools will fix it all up -- but it makes sense to me to comment on questionable activity only if you think your comment will positively influence someone else's behavior. If they're engaging in ill-will, just flag and be happy.